# TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html

What are the possible sources of this error? A brief context of what I'm trying to achieve. I found an epub scraper that downloads web pages and scraps the content of the web pages into an epub. I tried to edit the js but encountered this error. Previously, I managed to download 1 epub successfully but now its stuck on chapter 9.

Error with Stack Trace:

> ```
> TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>         at Object.convert (C:\Users\T\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\worm-scraper\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\generated\Node.js:749:11)
>         at HTMLDivElement.removeChild (C:\Users\T\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\worm-scraper\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\generated\Node.js:323:29)
>         at getBodyXML (C:\Users\T\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\worm-scraper\lib\convert.js:60:15)
>         at getChapterString (C:\Users\T\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\worm-scraper\lib\convert.js:40:16)
>         at convertChapter (C:\Users\T\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\worm-scraper\lib\convert.js:27:18)
>         at <anonymous>
> ```

The code I believe is causing the issue is:

```
function getBodyXML(chapter, contentEl) {


 // Remove initial Next Chapter and Previous Chapter <p>
  //contentEl.removeChild(contentEl.firstElementChild);

  // Remove everything after the last <p> (e.g. analytics <div>s)
  const lastP = contentEl.querySelector("p:last-of-type");
  while (contentEl.lastElementChild !== lastP) {
    contentEl.removeChild(contentEl.lastElementChild);
  }

  // Remove empty <p>s or Last Chapter/Next Chapter <p>s
  while (isEmptyOrGarbage(contentEl.lastElementChild)) {
    contentEl.removeChild(contentEl.lastElementChild);
  }

  // Remove redundant attributes and style
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(contentEl.children, child => {
    if (child.getAttribute("dir") === "ltr") {
      child.removeAttribute("dir");
    }

    // Only ever appears with align="LEFT" (useless) or align="CENTER" overridden by style="text-align: left;" (also
    // useless)
    child.removeAttribute("align");

    if (child.getAttribute("style") === "text-align:left;") {
      child.removeAttribute("style");
    }
    if (child.getAttribute("style") === "text-align:left;padding-left:30px;") {
      child.setAttribute("style", "padding-left:30px;");
    }
  });
```

if it helps, the original scraper is called `worm-scraper` and the edited version is uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PuFpAiLB5Ya_OAqegTV1GQi5NZGPM-Jg?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you do not put your code, it is difficult that someone can help you.

Comment: Hi! Please have a look around and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question.

Comment: Separately: The error seems fairly clear: Code somewhere has `someNode.removeChild(x)` where `x` is not a node.